# Jquery SmartWizard Add Extra Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, smart-wizard

How to add the extra buttons in [jquery smart wizard](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard)

**Tried Code :**

I have added the toolbar section code.. Still its not working. Can someone help me on this?

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnXmp/75/)

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard({
            transitionEffect: 'slide',
            keyNavigation: false,
            onLeaveStep:leaveAStepCallback,
            onShowStep:showAStepCallBack,
            labelNext:'Save', 
            labelPrevious:'Back',
            labelFinish:'Finish',
      enableFinishButton: true,
            selected: 0,
        // step bar options
        toolbarSettings: {
          toolbarPosition: 'bottom', // none, top, bottom, both
          toolbarButtonPosition: 'left', // left, right
          showNextButton: false, // show/hide a Next button
          showPreviousButton: true, // show/hide a Previous button
          toolbarExtraButtons: ['NextBtn']
        }, 
        });
```

**Expected Output**

I'm trying to add one more button near to "Next" button.

Comment: this plugin is no more maintained. If you need to updated funcionalities you need to fork it on github.....  **toolbarSettings** comes from another wizard plugin. It seems you are messing up the code.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone has the same problem, try this way:

```
    $('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
        toolbarSettings: {
            toolbarExtraButtons: [
                $('<button></button>').text('Finish')
                            .addClass('btn btn-info')
                            .on('click', function(){ 
                                alert('Finish button click');                            
                            }),
                $('<button></button>').text('Cancel')
                            .addClass('btn btn-danger')
                            .on('click', function(){ 
                                alert('Cancel button click');                            
                            })
            ]
        },
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

In document.ready() function you can append you extra button like:

```
$('.actionBar').append("<button class='buttonNext'>Extra</button>")
```

you can give your class and id so you can call any function on button click.

Comment: This has no effect in the current version, and it is misleading people.

Comment: @NorbertBoros, as per the question asked the answer is right, and in my given solution I have written a pure jQuery and it is not misleading anyone. If you know the correct answer then please post it.